# How to calculate django model fields

Tags: jquery, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have the following fields in my models:

```
class Materiale(models.Model):
    quantity=models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    price=models.DecimalField( max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    VAT=models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    VAT_amount=models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
```

But the VAT_amount is the result of `quantity*price*VAT`.

How can store in my database that value automatically??? It's important that the field (VAT_amount) is 
present in database.

Thanks.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please *don't* store this in your database. If it fully depends on other fields, it is often better to *calculate* the column. Indeed, imagine that you *update* one of the fields, then you will need to update the `VAT_amount` as well. But if you make a lot of views, queries, etc. then eventually you will likely make a mistake and forget to update.

You can remove the `VAT_amount` field, and then `.annotate(..)` your queryset to include the `VAT_amount`, for example:

```
from django.db.models import F

Materiale.objects.annotate(VAT_amount=F('quantity')*F('price')*F('vat'))
```

The `Materiale` objects that arise from *this* queryset will have an extra attribute `.VAT_amount` then that contains the result of the formula.

If you need this often, you can add that to the *manager* of this model, such that it is done automatically each time you access `Materiale.objects`:

```
class MetarialeManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).annotate(
            VAT_amount=F('quantity')*F('price')*F('vat')
        )

class Materiale(models.Model):
    quantity=models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    price=models.DecimalField( max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    VAT=models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0)

    objects = MaterialeManager()
```

Comment: why not make it a property instead?

Comment: @VishalSingh: because with an annotation, you can also filter at the *database side*, use it in other annotations, etc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks you it works perfectly. Only a question: if I want that VAT_amount have only two decimal? How can I get this?